# Zend Framework - Returning Image/File using Controller

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to Zend Framework 2 and only know a little basics. I find it difficult to find a lot of examples as well.

Quesiton: Get BLOB field in database and display it through a controller. For example: www.mysite.com/images/2 will retrieve a BLOB from the database and display it to the user as an image so an html tag like `<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/2"/>` will display an image.

I normally do it in ASP.NET MVC but have no clue how to do it here. I would be delighted if some one could enlighten me on how to achieve it.

Assume that I have fetched the image from the database.

I managed to find how to return JSON and believe some thing simple like that would work. But couldn't find the solution. I will also need to send files like that.

```
public function displayAction()
{
    $id = 10;
    $albumImage = $this->getAlbumImageTable()->getAlbumImage($id);

    if ($albumImages){
        //Show the image $albumImage
        //return JsonModel(array(...)) for json but for image ???
    } else{
        //Show some other image
    }
}
```

I would be obliged if some one could help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*As of Zend Framework 2.0 to 2.1*

If you want to return an image, simply return the response object filled in with the content: that will tell the `Zend\Mvc\Application` to entirely skip the `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER` event and go to `Zend\Mvc\Application::EVENT_FINISH`

```
public function displayAction()
{
    // get image content
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    $response->setContent($imageContent);
    $response
        ->getHeaders()
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent));

    return $response;
}
```

This will cause the application to [short-circuit](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php#L265-L273) to the `Zend\Mvc\Event::EVENT_FINISH`, which in turn is capable of sending the response to the output.

Comment: That is really neat, I had some problem with `mb_strlen`, I removed it :D.

Comment: This is a very CPU-consume action, do you know any solutions?

Comment: For me `mb_strlen` does not work, `strlen` is needed instead. If you're getting not full image, or error about malformed response, you may try this. Removing whole altogether also may work as Ziyan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ocramius' code, if you are uploading the images into a folder inside the application, you can retrieve the content, using:

```
$imageContent =  file_get_contents('data/image/photos/default.png');
$response->setContent($imageContent);
$response
    ->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent));

return $response;
```