# Zend Framework 2 and Imagine

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am working on a CMS built on top of Zend framework 2.
There needs to come a function which resizes images, after some research I found [Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/introduction.html#installation)

It has all the functions I need. On the website it says you need to require the libary on your page.

With Zend Framework 2 you can't just include the file but you need some factory for it. Now is the problem i'm not to familiar with Zend Framework 2 but we need a fast solution.

I hope one of you guys can help out with a solution.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832891/image-resize-zf2

Answer (score 2):

In composer.json, load the library:

```
"require": {
    "imagine/Imagine": "dev-master",
}
```

(don't forget composer update)
Then declare the service into Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'image_service' => 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine',
        ),
}
```

So you can call from a service or from your controller:

```
/** @var $imagine \Imagine\Gd\Imagine */
$imagine = $serviceManager->get('image_service');
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day!!