# How to resize a image while uploading in ZF2

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2, image-resizing

I'm new to Zend Frame work and I need to implement image resize while uploading in zend framework 2. I try to use the method in [image resize zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832891/image-resize-zf2) but it didnot work for me.

please help?

public function addAction(){

```
    $form = new ProfileForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();  
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $profile = new Profile();
        $form->setInputFilter($profile->getInputFilter());
        $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();

        $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('fileupload');
        $width   = $this->params('width', 30); // @todo: apply validation!
        $height  = $this->params('height', 30); // @todo: apply validation!
        $imagine = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my_image_service');
        $image   = $imagine->open($File['tmp_name']);
        $transformation = new \Imagine\Filter\Transformation();
        $transformation->thumbnail(new \Imagine\Image\Box($width, $height));
        $transformation->apply($image);

        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setContent($image->get('png'));
        $response
            ->getHeaders()
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent));
        return $response;
        $data = array_merge(
             $nonFile,
             array('fileupload'=> $File['name'])
         );
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $size = new Size(array('min'=>100000)); //minimum bytes filesize
            $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
            $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);
            if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                {
                    $error[] = $row;
                }
                $form->setMessages(array('fileupload'=>$error ));
            } else {
                $adapter->setDestination('./data/tmpuploads/');

                if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) { //identify the uploaded errors
                    $profile->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                    echo 'Profile Name '.$profile->profilename.' upload '.$profile->fileupload;
                }
            }  
        } 
    }          
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Related to :-[image resize zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832891/image-resize-zf2?rq=1)

Comment: Could you be little more specific??

Comment: I can upload a image..but i cannot resize that..

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832891/image-resize-zf2

Comment: I have no idea,that how to include the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832891/image-resize-zf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer for this question by adding external library to zend module.It is a easy way for me. i used http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/ class as external library.this is my controller class.

class ProfileController extends AbstractActionController{

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new ProfileForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();  
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $profile = new Profile();
        $form->setInputFilter($profile->getInputFilter());

        $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
        $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('fileupload');

        $data = array_merge(
             $nonFile,
             array('fileupload'=> $File['name'])
         );

        //set data post and file ...    
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $size = new Size(array('min'=>100000)); //minimum bytes filesize

            $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
            $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);
            if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                {
                    $error[] = $row;
                }
                $form->setMessages(array('fileupload'=>$error ));
            } else {
                $adapter->setDestination('//destination for upload the file');
                if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) {
                    $profile->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                    //print_r($profile);
                    echo 'Profile Name '.$profile->profilename.' upload '.$profile->fileupload;

                    $image = new SimpleImage(); 
                    $image->load('//destination of the uploaded file');
                    $image->resizeToHeight(500);
                    $image->save('//destination for where the resized file to be uploaded');



                }
            }  
        } 
    }

    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

}

Related:-[Zend Framework 2 - How to use an external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522772/zend-framework-2-how-to-use-an-external-library)
http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/