# Dynamically Render jpg/png from string inside php page

Tags: php, zend-framework2, gd

I need to render an image (png) from a string (a user's telephone number), when the page is rendered. It's possible to render the image inside a php page? or I have to create a page exclusively to render the image and I'll include it?

If I use this code inside my php page, doesn't work correctly

```
    <?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

I must declare "header('Content-type: image/png')" or there is another way to render a png? because if I declare it, the other parts of the page aren't rendered.

I'm using Zend Framework 2

As he suggested me, I tried to use base64 way and works fine

```
    <?php 
 ob_start (); 
 $im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);

$image_data = ob_get_contents (); 

ob_end_clean (); 

$image_data_base64 = base64_encode ($image_data);

?>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $image_data_base64; ?>" alt="img"/ >
```

**disclaymer** 
it's a test, don't coping and using this code in your site, it's insecure.

Comment: Did you check out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14811182/199593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all web pages - images are not a part of HTML - they are separate files. So yes, you DO have to create a separate file and set appropriate headers for your image. And then just include the file's url in your image's source.

Have in mind though that if your url is something like "file.php?number=123456", then it's easy for robots to know the phone number and it will just defeat the purpose of the image (if i assume the purpose correctly).

Alternatively, you could generate an image, convert it to base64 and embed it in the actual HTML source as a data-uri. I wouldn't recommend that, but if you're interested, just google "html data-uri" - you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: Why you don't recommend me base64 way?

Comment: Base64 data uris are relatively "new" so might not work on all the browsers you need them to work on, as opposed to external files that have been used like this for a long long time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Marius. It's better to call another file to generate the image.

```
<img src="phoneimg.php?n=123-456-7890.png" />
// or base64_encode() the number
<img src="phoneimg.php?n=MTIzLTQ1Ni03ODkw.png" />
```

Use a url query string to send the number,extension,size etc. Remember to filter and sanitize the incoming query before proceeding.